# I'm not sure how Dn gets the value in the black box

Tags: real-analysis

Could you help me understand the solution for this question?

I'm not sure how $D_n$ gets the value in the black box.

Question:
[image]

Answer:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have, with that choice of $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$

$$\begin{align}
f(\beta_n) &= 0\\
f(\alpha_n) &= \alpha_n^2\\
\beta_n - \alpha_n &= \frac{1}{2n\pi} - \frac{1}{\pi/2+2n\pi} = \frac{\pi/2}{2n\pi(\pi/2+2n\pi)} = \frac{\alpha_n}{4n}
\end{align}$$

Thus we obtain

$$\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} = -\alpha_n^2\frac{4n}{\alpha_n} = -4n\alpha_n = \frac{-4n}{\pi/2+2n\pi}$$

With a gratuitous multiplication of numerator and denominator by $\pi$, you obtain the given expression.

Comment: I suspect the gratious multiplication is necessary because the author of the book calculated $D_n$ in some other way where that $\pi$ appears without being forcefully inserted. But that's just speculating. I think the author should've shortened it in the first place.

Comment: Probably the author just didn't cancel the $\pi$s in $\beta_n - \alpha_n$.